# < and > converted into &lt; &gt; in React js render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build Markdown previewer with React and [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked). Here is my code:

```
var Input = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {typed: 'I am using __markdown__.'};
  },
  onChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({typed: event.target.value});
  },
  render: function() {

    const element = (
      <div id="container">
      <div id="input-container">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="20" id="main-input" onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
      <div id="result-container">
        {marked(this.state.typed)}
      </div>
      </div>
    );
    return element;
  }
});
React.render(<Input/>, document.querySelector('div'));
```

The result is this:

```
<div id="result-container" data-reactid=".0.1">&lt;p&gt;I am using &lt;strong&gt;markdown&lt;/strong&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;
</div>
```

Why is this happening? How should I fix it? (I tried to replace all the < and > with < and > inside render. But that didn't work)

Comment: You may have to use `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{_html: marked(this.state.typed)}} />`.

Comment: @Brian wow that was it. Thanks.